# How to raise a vector to the power in matlab?

Tags: matlab, vector, vectorization

Using `FreeMat` I've been trying to raise a vector to the power of two, using this code:

```
v=[4 -3 8 -7 2 -10 11 4]

disp('v before = ')
disp(v)

for i=1:1:length(v)
if (v<0) & (v>-8)
    v(i)=v(i)^2

end   
end

 disp('v after = ')
 disp(v)
```

but **it keeps returning the same values.**

- Why?
- And what's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

```
if (v<0) & (v>-8)
```

to

```
if (v(i)<0) & (v(i)>-8)
```

Answer (score 1):

why won't you vectorize it with logical indexing? no for loops \ if conditions needed:

```
v(v<0 & v>-8)=v(v<0 & v>-8).^2
```